# Oracle 19c zero hour default date format with time without using any formating function

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle19c

I am trying to insert **zero hour** 20 mins date with time **without using any formatting function**, but I am getting some errors as follows

```
insert into employee(created_date) values('4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM');
```

ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 to 12

how to insert **zero hour** in oracle 19c **without using any formatting function**

Comment: Well there is no 00h in AM/PM system. Maybe you're looking for 12 AM?

Comment: Where is the string value coming from, is it always formatted the same, and how does it show values in the afternoon? As that value is invalid, is 1 PM shown as 01:00:00 PM or 13:00:00 PM? The latter would allow you to just strip the (pointless/wrong) AM/PM indicator off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without using any formatting function

That would be a really bad idea. It means that you're about to insert a **string** into a `DATE` datatype column, hoping that Oracle will "recognize" that string, implicitly convert it to a valid `DATE` datatype value and insert it into a column. There are just too many "what if"s that might go wrong and - sooner or later - some of them will.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, datum date);

Table created.
```

This is your query:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, '4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM');
insert into test (id, datum) values (1, '4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM')
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

I'll apply `to_date` to it, using appropriate format model (yes, I know, you don't want that - just see what happens):

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM', 'dd/Mon/yy hh:mi:ss am'));
insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM', 'dd/Mon/yy hh:mi:ss am'))
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

How come "Jan" is not a valid month? Well, it is not. In Croatia (and that's the language my database speaks), it is "Sij". But OK, I can add additional parameter to `TO_DATE`:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM', 'dd/Mon/yy hh:mi:ss am', 'nls_date_language = english'));
insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('4/Jan/21 00:20:00 AM', 'dd/Mon/yy hh:mi:ss am', 'nls_date_language = english'))
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
```

As Zakaria commented, `00` is an invalid value; change it to `12`:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('4/Jan/21 12:20:00 AM', 'dd/Mon/yy hh:mi:ss am', 'nls_date_language = english'));

1 row created.
```

Not it succeeded. What did I insert? Right, that's 20 minutes past midnight.

```
SQL> select id, to_date(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datum from test;

        ID DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 04.01.2021 00:20:00

SQL>
```

---

If you insist on what you asked, then make sure Oracle understands it.

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mon/yy hh:mi:ss am';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, '4/Jan/21 12:20:00 AM');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID DATUM
---------- ---------------------
         1 04/jan/21 12:20:00 AM

SQL>
```

If I were you, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: I went for to_date with 24 hour format, as I myself realized even before reading this

Comment: Good choice; I'd also suggest you to switch to numbers for months as well (i.e 01 instead of Jan(uary) and - of course - 4 digits for years.

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

A `DATE` is a binary data type that consists of 7 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second); it **ALWAYS** contains those components and is **NEVER** stored with any particular format.

If you want to store a data and a time then you can either use:

1. A `DATE` literal and an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` literal:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO employee(created_date)
   VALUES ( DATE '2021-01-04' + INTERVAL '00:20:00' HOUR TO SECOND);
   ```

   This requires the date in ISO 8601 format and the time in the 24-hour clock.
2. A `TIMESTAMP` literal (which will be implicitly cast to a `DATE`):

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO employee(created_date) VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2021-01-04 00:20:00');
   ```

   This requires the date and time in ISO 8601 format (with a space instead of `T` between the date and time components) and the time in the 24-hour clock.
3. Explicit conversion from string-to-date:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO employee(created_date) VALUES (
     TO_DATE(
       '4/Jan/21 12:20:00 AM',
       'DD/Mon/RR HH12:MI:SS AM',
       'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
     )
   );
   ```

   You can explicitly set the format and language you wish to be used. *(Note: in a 12-hour clock you want `12` instead of `00` for the hours.)*
4. Implicit conversion from string-to-date:

   First, set the format model to be used with implicit string-to-date (or date-to-string) conversions:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/Mon/RR HH12:MI:SS AM';
   ```

   Then:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO employee(created_date) VALUES ('4/Jan/21 12:20:00 AM');
   ```
5. Something non-standard, like directly creating the binary `DATE` value:

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION createDate(
     year   int,
     month  int,
     day    int,
     hour   int,
     minute int,
     second int
   ) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
   IS
     hex CHAR(14);
     d DATE;
   BEGIN
    hex := TO_CHAR( FLOOR( year / 100 ) + 100, 'fm0X' )
         || TO_CHAR( MOD( year, 100 ) + 100, 'fm0X' )
         || TO_CHAR( month, 'fm0X' )
         || TO_CHAR( day, 'fm0X' )
         || TO_CHAR( hour + 1, 'fm0X' )
         || TO_CHAR( minute + 1, 'fm0X' )
         || TO_CHAR( second + 1, 'fm0X' );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( hex );
     DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_VALUE( HEXTORAW( hex ), d );
     RETURN d;
   END;
   /
   ```

   Then:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO employee(created_date)
   VALUES (createDate(2021,1,4,0,20,0));
   ```

---

Options 1, 2 & 3 are standard ways of creating dates.

Option 4 is bad practice (since any user can change their own session parameters at any time so the query will fail if they `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is changed from your expected format) but will work if you can guarantee the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` will not be changed.

Option 5 is only really useful for creating malformed or erroneous dates for testing purposes since it bypasses the normal error checking process.

> how to insert **zero hour** in oracle 19c without using **any formatting function**

The only one of those options that uses a formatting function is Option 3. However, options 1, 2 and 5 involve formatting the date differently to your format and option 4 requires you to set the implicit format model in a separate statement.